# Anything similar to MFMessageComposeViewController on Android?

Tags: android, ios, sms, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I found that in iOS you can easily access a view controller `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send and receive SMS texts.

Is there anything similar to this on Android?

More more documentation:

[MFMessageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything similar to this on Android?

No, not really, unless you consider opening another SMS app via an `Intent` to have similar functionality. If your app is to handle the SMS all on its own, you'll have to build your own UI.

Comment: Damn, was hoping to avoid this.

Comment: Good places to start on building a wrapper around SMSManager?

Comment: You could have a look at the [platform app source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/master). The GUI definitions are in [/res/layout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/master/res/layout/). They provide a good example to start designing your layouts. This is a full-blown SMS/MMS app, though, so depending on the extent of the needed SMS functionality, the underlying code might be a little more cumbersome to sift through. There are plenty of posts here on SO, however, that can provide you with examples to get working just what is necessary.